# pg_query(): 4 is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource

Tags: php, postgresql

Very interesting error i have just encountered and i am not sure why is it and i am scratching my head on what went wrong and where.

As per title the error is 'not valid postgres resourse' which is weird to me because:

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');

class Processor {
    public function list_data() {
        global $db;

        $sql = "select * from sales_data where id >= 0;";
        $ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
        if(!$ret) {
            // echo pg_last_error($db);
        } else {
            // echo "Records listed sucessfully";
        }
        $data = pg_fetch_all($ret);
        pg_close($db);
        return $data;
    }
    public function delete_record($id, $first_name, $last_name) {   
        global $db;

        $sql = "update sales_data set id = -".$id." where id = ".$id;
        var_dump($sql);

        $ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
        if(!$ret){
            // echo pg_last_error($db);
        } else {
            // echo "Records created successfully\n";
        }
        pg_close($db);

        /* Redirect browser */
        // header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/sales/viewcontacts.php");
    }
}
?>
```

My list_data method works prefectly fine whereas my delete_record throws this error.

var_dump of sql shows: `string(42) "update sales_data set id = -3 where id = 3"`  which is perfectly valid (at least as far as postgres is concerned) syntax.

As suggested var_dump of `$db` shows  `resource(4) of type (Unknown)`

Comment: "var_dump of sql shows" - it's the other parameter one of the pg_* functions complains.

Comment: @VolkerK thats what i thought but then, why other method is working perfectly fine ?

Comment: No idea. Please use var_dump() on the other parameter ($db) anyway,

Comment: @VolkerK ok, so apparently $db is unknown

Comment: The error/warning message should contain a file name and a line number. a) Can you please mark that line in your code? b) is the code you've posted the actual code you're using or some abbreviated version? c) I don't want to sound holier-than-thou but that's one reason why `global` isn't such a great thing.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute..... you're calling `pg_close($db);` in both `list_data()` and `delete_record()`. After that the resource is more or less worthless. Am I right that you do not re-establish the postgresql connection between those two calls?

Comment: @VolkerK yup bingo :). after closing connection i do not have anywhere in the code to re-establish the connection if its closed. problem solved :) - make answer and i'll accept